# Isotropic oscilator $\vec{F}=-k \vec{r}$ in Classical Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Say we have a force $F=-k \vec{r}$ acting on a body at position $\vec{r}$. Say the body starts at $\vec{r_0}$ with velocity $\vec{v_0}$. We want to find under what initial conditions the body moves in a circle.

We have that $m \ddot{\vec{r}}=-k\vec{r}$ so that $$\vec{r(t)}=\vec{r_0} cosωt + \frac{\vec{v_0}}{ω} sinωt$$
Where $ω=k/m$. 
 We know that since we have a central force its angular momentum is constant and therefore the motion is constrained in a plane. So for it to move in a circle it only needs to have constant $|\vec{r(t)}|$:

Now **IF** $\vec{v_0}$ and $\vec{r_0}$ are perpendicular then $$|\vec{r(t)}|=\sqrt{\vec{r_0}^2 cos^2ωt + \frac{\vec{v_0}^2}{ω^2} sin^2ωt} $$
It suffices to take $|\vec{r(t)}|^2$ constant so we need the time derivative of the expression under the root to be constant. I did that and found $$\frac{d|\vec{r(t)}|^2}{dt} =0 \implies |r_0|= \frac{|v_0|}{ω}$$

Which of course "translates" to $m v_0 ^2 /R =kR $ : the expression for the centripetal force, as expected.

So how do I show that in the beginning the velocity and the position must be perpendicular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful to think in *cylindrical polar coordinates* $(r,\theta)$. For simplicity, we only consider motion on the $xy$ plane. At any point on a general trajectory, the velocity is given by,
$$\mathbf{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$$
If the motion is constrained to be on the circle, then by definition, $\dot{r}=0$. So, velocity is only along the $\hat{\theta}$ direction, which is perpendicular to the $\hat{r}$ direction, i.e., to $\mathbf{r}$.

EDIT: Moving in a circle places a **kinematic** constraint on the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mathematical reason for $\dot {\mathbf r}\cdot\mathbf r = 0$ at any time; this equation $\ddot{\mathbf r} = -\omega^2\mathbf r$ admits the general solution,$$\mathbf r(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
A_x\cos(\omega t+\varphi_x)\\
A_y\cos(\omega t+\varphi_y)\\
A_z\cos(\omega t+\varphi_z)\\
\end{bmatrix},$$ where $\omega^2 = k/m$ and $A_{x,y,z},\varphi_{x,y,z}$ are six independent free parameters. One of these for example is $A_y=A_z=0$ where you have a standard 1-dimensional harmonic oscillator solution; you would never expect $\dot {\mathbf r}\cdot\mathbf r = 0$ in that case. On the other hand indeed we have $A_z = 0, A_x=A_y, \varphi_x = \varphi_y \pm \pi/2$ where we do have circular solutions and $\dot{\mathbf r}\cdot\mathbf r = 0$ at all times.

We can of course see that $\|\mathbf r\|$ constant is the same as saying that $\|\mathbf r\|^2=\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf r$ is constant and taking a time derivative that is exactly equivalent to $2 \dot{\mathbf r}\cdot \mathbf r = 0$ and therefore exactly equivalent to $\dot{\mathbf r}\cdot \mathbf r = 0$. We can also go one step further and say that whatever $q=\dot{\mathbf r}\cdot \mathbf r$ is, its time derivative is $\dot q = -\omega^2 \mathbf r\cdot \mathbf r + \dot{\mathbf r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf r}.$ This is a wonderful expression because one more derivative gives
$$\ddot q = -4\omega^2 \dot{\mathbf r}\cdot \mathbf r =-4\omega^2q.$$Demanding $q=0$ at all times is thus fulfilled by $q=0,\dot q=0$ at any one time.

Indeed your argument for reducing dimensionality to 2D can be used to argue that all solutions are ellipses, as another way to come to this same conclusion.